# Столбец не существует PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос, я его пытался составить...

```
SELECT "news".id,"news".uri,"news".title,"news".date,
replace( replace( replace( replace("news".uri,'http://www...ru/gal.php?cat=',''), 'http://www...ru/gal.php?pr=',''), 'http://...ru/gal.php?pr=', '' ),'http://www...ru/pr.php','' )::integer AS photorep
FROM news W1
JOIN pr_photoreport W2
ON W2.id = W1.photorep
WHERE "news".uri <> ''
```

В общем, нужно чтобы он не ругался.
в строчке `ON W2.id = W1.photorep`
он не может понять почему photorep не существует, как это можно исправить?

Comment: ну так напишите `ON replace( replace( replace( replace(W1.uri,'http://www...ru/gal.php?cat=',''), 'http://www...ru/gal.php?pr=',''), 'http://...ru/gal.php?pr=', '' ),'http://www...ru/pr.php','' )::integer = w2.id` наверно он не понимает  псевдонимов из списка полей select-а

Comment: И не наверно, а точно. синонимы из списка выборки нельзя использовать в ON или WHERE. Либо копируйте целиком весь replace в ON, либо оборачивайте в еще один select, где этот синоним будет уже обычной колонкой и делайте join к нему. А вообще если вам приходится клеить таблицы по такому жуткому условию - значит у вас не верно спроектирована БД

Comment: Это предыдущие разработчики не могли нормально связать один объект с другим, и связывали это все по средствам обычных ссылок... а не по ID'ам, что было бы логичнее.